excel automation to copy and paste values within a column where the first row equals a data value specified on a different worksheet
Is there a way to get an automate scrip to read a value in a given cell on one worksheet, and then find that value in row 1 of a second worksheet and then copy & paste values for all cells in that column?

The date value of the data is always in cell A1 of Worksheet 1
Formulas transpose the data from Worksheet 1 into worksheets 2 to 38 according to the date in cell A1 of Worksheet 1
So that new data can be inserted into Worksheet 1, I need to overwrite the formulas in the correct columns on worksheets 2 to 38 with the values (copy & paste values)

If there is a solution using an automate script that would be great. Using a product other than excel isn't an option, the data has to be retained in excel on our SharePoint site for governance reasons.

Can't you just use VBA and get the value you want from a cell in the selected worksheet, put it in a variable, and post it to the worksheet you want to change? Seems like a fairly straightforward, commonly done thing in Excel VBA, and its object model allows for the specification of worksheets by name (and their cell contents). So in answer to your question:  yes there is a solution, look at the Excel object model and VBA to solve the problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
